# Delete method vbscript producing path not found error when the path is valid

Tags: vbscript

```
strFolderPathToDelete = strBackupFoldToDelete & strInternationalDate

set objFSOFolderToDelete = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set objDeleteFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Wscript.Echo strFolderPathToDelete the folder path is valid

set objDeleteFolder = objFSOFolderToDelete.GetFolder(strFolderPathToDelete)

'Wscript.Echo objDeleteFolder the folder path is valid

objDeleteFolder.Delete true ' why this line produces error path not found?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `DeleteFolder` method of the **FileSystemObject** to see if that helps, and surround it with some error-handling with the hopes of isolating the problem, like so:

```
strFolderPathToDelete = strBackupFoldToDelete & strInternationalDate

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If .FolderExists(strFolderPathToDelete) Then
        On Error Resume Next : Err.Clear
        .DeleteFolder strFolderPathToDelete, True
        If 0 = Err.Number Then 
            WScript.Echo "Successfully deleted folder: " & strFolderPathToDelete
        Else
            WScript.Echo "Error (" & CStr(Err.Number) & ") deleting folder: " & Err.Description
        End If
        On Error Goto 0
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Sorry, folder does not exist: " & strFolderPathToDelete
    End If
End With
```

It's quite possible the folder might be a symbolic link or junction to another physical path, or perhaps a DFS link or share that you don't have sufficient DELETE permissions to.

Also, ensure the folder is empty (not containing any hidden or system files), and ensure it not being accessed (with any open handles) prior to deleting it.  Enterprise security, anti-virus, and backup solutions can occassionally cause unexpected problems -- as well as malware on infected systems.

Hope this helps.